# What does the comma mean in a card effect's cost?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Some cards, such as [Lurking Informant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=83834), have a comma seperating 2 costs for an ability. What does that mean? Do I pay one of the costs or both to use the effect?

Comment: The comma is used to separate different *kinds* of costs (e.g., tapping, sacrificing, mana)

Comment: @Hao Ye, That's inaccurate. There's only one cost. The comma separates the components of the cost.

Comment: @ikegami It IS actually accurate, just perhaps poorly worded. What she means is the different types of costs, as one cost can have multiple types of costs required; in Lurking Informant's case, this is Tapping and Paying Mana.

Comment: @Waterseas, I knew what Hao Ye *meant*, but they said there was more than one cost. And now, you go and do the same thing. Please stop saying the commas separate costs of different types. There is only one cost. "Different types of payment" works, but "components of the cost" works better.

Comment: @ikegami That's not logic. One cost can have multiple types of costs incorporated into it. It's still correct to say that. An example: Purple is a color that contains multiple primary colors. Am I saying purple IS multiple colors? No. It simply is comprised of multiple primary colors.

Comment: @ikegami '"One cost can have multiple types of costs incorporated into it." makes no sense. I assumed you meant "One cost can have costs of multiple types incorporated into it"' Those sentences have two entirely different meanings. If you can't comprehend the difference, even with my comparable example, then there is no point in further continuing this discussion.

Comment: @Ikegami No, costs aren't made of types, but there are multiple types of costs, and a single cost can have multiple things required to be paid (aka, different types of costs). There was literally no grammar mistake in the sentence I used, so unfortunately, can't fix the thing that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Waterseas, Re "a single cost can have multiple things required to be paid", So that's what you wanted to say? Why? Did you believe I said or believed otherwise? As I already said "components of the cost" is a better word than "thing". (And please stop saying you can "pay types". That makes no sense.)

Comment: @Ikegami That is indeed another way of saying what I already said. In addition, yet again, your parenthesis are not a correct interpretation of the english used in the sentence, but given the many ways I have tried to explain to you why it is incorrect, I shall not keep trying.

Comment: @ikegami Really not sure why you're attempting to be such a grammar nazi. In addition, you're still missing a key word in your 'quotes'; the primary subject. Am gonna be the better person here and not reply further after this though, though feel free to reply anyways if you'd like.

Comment: @Waterseas, I was just trying to makes sense of poorly written communications directed at me. Or are you referring to my comment correcting the misstatement saying there's more than one cost being payed? Precise terminology is quite important when explaining rules in general, and particularly important in this case. Or are you referring to my suggestion of using "components of cost" instead of "things"? Because I'm nice like that.

Comment: @Waterseas, You mentioned there was something incorrect, but you never said what. You wouldn't be a better person by not replying. If there's something to fix, let's fix it. So far you've said "A single cost can have multiple things required to be paid" is an explanation of some error. What's the error?

Comment: Re "you're still missing a key word in your 'quotes'; the primary subject.", I omitted the description of the type (which isn't a subject; nouns don't have subjects), because it doesn't make sense to pay types, no matter what kind of types they are. Please don't tell people they can pay types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a single cost and you pay both parts. [From the Comprehensive Rules:](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Activation_cost)

> 602.1 Activated abilities have a cost and an effect. They are written as “[Cost]: [Effect.] [Activation instructions (if any).]”
>
> 602.1a The activation cost is everything before the colon (:). An ability’s activation cost must be paid by the player who is activating it.
>
> Example: The activation cost of an ability that reads “{2}, {T}: You gain 1 life” is two mana of any type plus tapping the permanent that has the ability.